# Change currency on Placester

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Real Estate Website builder plugin for a Placester theme on Wordpress.
Currently, it lists the currency in USD ($). I want to change this to another currency i.e, Indian Rupee (INR). I know this is possible but I don't know how.

I've read through their website on placester.com as well as the readme.txt file that comes bundled with the theme and plugin but nothing seems to stand out on how to change the settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few convoluted steps involved in fixing this.

For the home page,

1. You figure out where the $ icon appears. Turns out, in the theme I used it is hard coded in the CSS file under `price-ico` class.
2. Using FTP, access the wp-content//css/style.css file.
3. Find the appropriate class and remove the `background` property.
4. Next, find the `home-slideshow.php` file in the Editor panel of the WP Dashboard. Find the `price-ico` tag and insert the required symbol before the line that says `<?php echo PLS_Format::number($listing['cur_data']['price'], array('abbreviate' => false, 'add_currency_sign' => false));`
5. Save file

For the rest of the pages, go to the Wordpress dashboard. Click on Appearance and go to Theme options.

Under currency symbol, change the $ to the respective currency. In my case it was INR(Rs).